# Where can I download intel hd vga driver for my dell inspiron n5010?

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, vga

i have a Dell inspiron n5010 Core i3 with intel hd vga i'm running ubuntu 11.10, i want to download and install the vga driver, i used the update manager but it didn't update my driver

Answer (score 2):

Linux intel drivers are well supported by the Kernel and the X-system.  You should be able to watch HD videos etc with the standard drivers that come with a default install.

I have an intel i3 CPU with Arrandale intel graphics and they work great.

Oneiric has the most recent and stable graphics drivers for Intel - you shouldnt need to install PPAs such as X-Stable or X-Edgers - these are testing PPAs.

If you have any specific issues then you should add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

to manage your drivers under Ubuntu trough a graphical interface you can use jockey

```
jockey-gtk
```

you can get info about your vga using the following command in a terminal

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

Since this driver do not have a really good and stable behaviour, various ppa are used to try to fix some bad issues, the most popular are

https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver

and

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates

you can add a ppa to your system with

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:[ppa name]
```

for lazy people this mean

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
```

or

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

considering only the previous ppa.

after that you can update your software list with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install the required packages with

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

after that reboot your machine.